¿Hacer que un frame gane el foco, cuando otro cierra en java?
Abriendo un frame desde otro usando:
Frame nuevoFrame = new Frame();
nuevoFrame.setVisible(true);
Hice que el primero no se cerrara, existe una manera en la que si se cierra el frame secundario yo dirija al usuario al frame original.
Lo pregunto por que además, estaba pensado en si minimizaba el primer frame y cuando se cerrara el segundo, volviera a dirigir el foco en el primero

¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? bloquear un jframe al abrir otro jframe
